# Need Elasticsearch guidance for searching on an array of chemical compounds

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of products and array of chemical compounds for each product, i.e. **['Sodium', 'Sodium bicarbonate', .....]**. In this example **'sodium'**, and **'sodium bicarbonate'** are two different values that can be search on independently, which complicates things, so using the text keyword field criteria did not help.

I need some guidance on the best method to handle these array of strings within Elasticsearch while retaining Elasticsearch's indexing magic. I appreciate any help you can provide.

FYI
I'm currently using Elasticsearch 6.3

Comment: Got a more concrete use case? What queries are you gunning for? What's currently *not working*?

Comment: I am open to suggestions on how to approach the problem, but the closest example i can think of is that of a tagging system. I need to search for products that have the following tags "sodium", and "sodium bicarbonate". What is the best way to configure such a field in elastic search to allow this type of query.

Comment: what currently is not working is rendering an array of strings ['sodium', 'sodium bicarbonate'] into a single string ''sodium sodium bicarbonate" and using this as a text field in elastic search. If I wanted to ask elastic search for a unique list of chemical compounds it would not be accurate due to the overlap with the sodium token. Further more i cant get results on items that have only sodium but not sodium bicarbonate. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), which builds on the match query to allow multi-field queries**

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result.

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "product": "product1",
  "compounds": [
    "Sodium",
    "Sodium bicarbonate"
  ]
}
{
  "product": "product2",
  "compounds": [
    "Sodium"
  ]
}
{
  "product": "product3",
  "compounds": [
    "Sodium bicarbonate"
  ]
}
{
  "product": "product4",
  "compounds": [
   "Chlorine
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "Sodium AND Sodium bicarbonate", 
      "fields": [ "compounds", "compounds.keyword" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65513968",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0897084,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product1",
          "compounds": [
            "Sodium",
            "Sodium bicarbonate"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65513968",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0659102,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product3",
          "compounds": [
            "Sodium bicarbonate"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65513968",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.7032229,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product",
          "compounds": [
            "Sodium"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) if you want to return documents that contain one or more exact terms in a field**

### A unique list of chemical compounds

To find the unique lists of chemical compounds you can use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "compounds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "compounds.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "compounds": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Sodium",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Sodium bicarbonate",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Chlorine",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @juan_wick did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for your help, and I really appreciated the answer format you provided.